# scroll down - reverse

Tags: jquery, html, css

hello I have this html code:

```
 <style type="text/css">
    .container{
        width: 450;
        height: 400;
        border:1px solid;
        border-radius: 6px;
        background: #000;
    }
    .name{
        border-bottom:1px solid;
        background: #FFF;
    }
    .div_lines{
        max-height: 360px;
        background: #000;
        color:#FFF;
        overflow: auto;
        vertical-align: top;
    }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="name">show</div>
    <div class="div_lines">
    <code class="lines">
        <div class="line">1</div>
        <div class="line">2</div>
        <div class="line">3</div>
        <div class="line">4</div>
        <div class="line">5</div>
        <div class="line">6</div>
        <div class="line">7</div>
        <div class="line">8</div>
        <div class="line">9</div>
        <div class="line">10</div>
        <div class="line">11</div>
        <div class="line">12</div>
        <div class="line">13</div>
        <div class="line">14</div>
        <div class="line">15</div>
        <div class="line">16</div>
        <div class="line">17</div>
        <div class="line">18</div>
        <div class="line">19</div>
        <div class="line">20</div>
        <div class="line">21</div>
        <div class="line">22</div>
        <div class="line">23</div>
        <div class="line">24</div>
        <div class="line">25</div>
        <div class="line">26</div>
        <div class="line">27</div>
        <div class="line">28</div>
    </code>
    </div>
    </div>
```

but what i want to know is that is there a way to change the scroll down so that when i get to the point where it will show the scroll bar i will need to scroll up to view the past data instead of scrolling down? like a command prompt it will show the last inserted lines and you need to scroll up to see the previews information.

Comment: Please don't include "hope I'm clear Thanks :)" in your question. It is useless noise.

Comment: What is exactly a *"point where it will show the scroll bar"* ?

Comment: when there is a lot information and instead of overflowing it will show it as a scroll bar wit same height

Comment: I think you are looking for a  jquery plugin?

Comment: anything possible will be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make this piece of javascript code run whenever another line is inserted:

```
var lines=document.getElementsByClassName('line');
lines[lines.length-1].scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: I am seeing it fine. I have a jsfiddle example of it working: http://jsfiddle.net/markasoftware/6hJAA/